# Intersection points between two functions

Tags: functions

How can i find the intersection points between 
$$y=\frac{\pi}{4} x,\:\: y=\tan^3(x)$$
Thank you for your help.

I know that the first (the obvious one...) is $0$.

But how can i get another one?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you done so far?

Comment: So far i have found first intersection point, which is the obvious one (zero). But now i am kinda in the dark about the second one...

Answer (score 0):

Have you drawn the graph?  We can concentrate on $x \ge 0$ as $(x,y)$ being a solution means $(-x,-y)$ is also a solution.
[image]
You won't find solutions algebraically.  For large $x$ the solutions will be just below $k\pi + \frac \pi 2$  Any numerical technique should work well for the one near $x=0.682$.  The others are just below $(k+\frac 12) \pi$.  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x*pi%2F4%3D(tan(x))%5E3) finds

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer. I thought there is another algebraicall way that i don't know about :)